# What can i use instead of pivot table to only show the records that have values for multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a list of customers that have downloaded a software. In order to see which one of them is actively using the software, I need to check if there is any values for both of the columns "Activated", and "Downloaded". I used pivot table for this purpose; and had the count of these columns under the "Values" section. 
But, the problem is that it shows the count of each column separately. For example it shows 7 for activated column and 12 for the downloaded column. However, this does not mean that I have 7 active users. Because some of the values for the activated column do not have any values in the "downloaded" column. Do you have any suggestions on how to show the active users? 
Sample data:
for example here I only have 3 active users

```
User ID     Download Time   Activation Code
1                            I05G77LU
2            10/28/2016       Y7YHQF1K
3            12/2/2016  
4            12/7/2016       7C5WLTOO
5                            JI1Z0725
6            10/28/2016      MQZ0ZA1L
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and an example of what you'd like to see?  It is unclear whether you want to flag the records that have values in both columns or you just want a count.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn just did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can go about this, my way is similar to what others have provided here trying to help you.  The idea behind my suggestion is to create a flag in another column which is based on the two values needed to drive your results.  Ex:
=IF(AND(B2<>"",C2<>""),0,1)
You can probably simply copy paste this formula.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an additional column named Activation Status and then insert this formula in the `column D`. Take a look at the snapshot below

[image]

```
D2=IF((ISBLANK(B2)+ISBLANK(C2))=0,"Activated","Not Activated")
```

Then you can use Activation Status column to filter the data or use it in pivot.

To get the total count of activated user use this formula

In Desired Cell `=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B7))*NOT(ISBLANK(C2:C7)))`

Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the data source. Use a formula that returns a 1 if both "Activated" and "Downloaded" contains a value in that row, and a 0 if it does not.

Then you can use that column to summarize in the pivot table.

Edit after you posted sample data:

```
=IF(AND([@[Download Time]]>0,ISTEXT([@[Activation Code]])),1,0)
```

Enter this, copy down and sum that column in the pivot table.